# Gradle build failing to get dependency from custom maven repository

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-studio, build.gradle

I have created a custom maven repo on BitBucket following the [link](https://bitbucket.org/neil_rubens/rapidminer_maven-repo/wiki/Home). When trying to use the dependencies in my android project using Gradle I am getting following error

```
Executing tasks: [:app:compileDebugJava]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
Checksum missing at https://bitbucket.org/test/maven-repo/raw/master/repository/com/test/com/testCommon/1.0/testCommon-1.0.pom.sha1 due to: For input string: "<!"
Download https://bitbucket.org/test/maven-repo/raw/master/repository/com/test/com/testCommon/1.0/testCommon-1.0.pom

[Fatal Error] testCommon-1.0.pom:2:10: Already seen doctype.

Checksum missing at https://bitbucket.org/test/maven-repo/raw/master/repository/com/android/support/support-v4/20.0.0/support-v4-20.0.0.pom.sha1 due to: For input string: "<!"
Download https://bitbucket.org/test/maven-repo/raw/master/repository/com/android/support/support-v4/20.0.0/support-v4-20.0.0.pom

[Fatal Error] support-v4-20.0.0.pom:2:10: Already seen doctype.

Checksum missing at https://bitbucket.org/test/maven-repo/raw/master/repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/20.0.0/support-annotations-20.0.0.pom.sha1 due to: For input string: "<!"
Download https://bitbucket.org/test/maven-repo/raw/master/repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/20.0.0/support-annotations-20.0.0.pom

[Fatal Error] support-annotations-20.0.0.pom:2:10: Already seen doctype.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not resolve com.test.com:testCommon:1.0.
     Required by:
         SettingsAid:app:unspecified
      > Could not parse POM https://bitbucket.org/test/maven-repo/raw/master/repository/com/test/com/testCommon/1.0/testCommon-1.0.pom
         > Already seen doctype.
```

**I have changed the link.** But opening the link directly returns the checksum.

Below is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'maven'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.sampleapp"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        credentials {
            username "test@gmail.com"
            password "test"
        }
        url "https://bitbucket.org/test/maven-repo/raw/master/repository/"
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
    compile 'com.test.com:testCommon:1.0'
    compile files('libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar')
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I have also followed this [link](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html). Can anybody help me in fixing this.

Update 1:

When I checked ~.gradle folder, even after giving the credentials it is not logging in and saving the full page. When I changed my repo from **private** to **public** the code started working. But I do not want to make my repo public. How to make gradle to use the login credentials passed?

Thanks.

Comment: Are the URLs to the `pom.xml` correct?

Comment: Do I need to add POM.xml also in the project?

Comment: Not in your android project. But is `https://bitbucket.org/test/maven-repo/raw/master/repository/` a correct URL? Or did you just mask it in this post?

Comment: So in your `build.gradle`, you're sure that the repository URL is correct? Like you can copy-and-paste it into the browser, and it takes you to the repo.

Comment: Yep, in the build.gradle I have given proper link which I can access. Also when I try to access actual link  Could not parse POM https://bitbucket.org/test/maven-repo/raw/master/repository/com/test/com/testCommon/1.0/testCommon-1.0.pom, I can see the pom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My team and I solved it using the Bitbucket REST API, you could find more details in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30117276/4877779

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the issue by changing repo path to :

```
"https://"+username+":"+password+"@bitbucket.org/test/maven-repo/raw/master/repository/"
```

UserName and password are set in `gradle.properties`.

Answer (score 3):

i used to struggle against this problem for three days. according to your code, here is my solution. hope that save your life.

1. your maven url is wrong. please use the right api of bitbuckest.org. and the url format should be https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/team-or-user-name/prject-name/raw/branch-name. example: https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/yolonetltd/yolonet-mvn-repo/raw/releases/.
   **note that do not use api.bitbucket.org/2.0, use api.bitbucket.org/1.0!**

   ```
   repositories {
       mavenCentral()
           maven {
               credentials {
                   username "xxxxx" // note, not email, use login user name please!
                   password "xxxxx"
               }
               url "https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/test/maven-repo/raw/master" // note, use api 1.0, do not use api 2.0!
           }
       }
   ```
2. if your dependency is **aar** format, you should add `@aar` after the dependency description. dependencies closure should like below. otherwise gradle will throw dependency not found error.

   ```
   dependencies {
       ...
       compile 'com.test.com:testCommon:1.0@aar'
       ...
   }
   ```
3. make sure your remote bitbucket maven repository holds the complete files directory like below. otherwise gradle will also throw dependency not found error.

   ```
   |   ├── com
   │   ├── as-gradle
   │   │   └── demo
   │   │       └── localrepo
   │   │           ├── 1.0.0
   │   │           │   ├── localrepo-1.0.0.aar
   │   │           │   ├── localrepo-1.0.0.aar.md5
   │   │           │   ├── localrepo-1.0.0.aar.sha1
   │   │           │   ├── localrepo-1.0.0.pom
   │   │           │   ├── localrepo-1.0.0.pom.md5
   │   │           │   └── localrepo-1.0.0.pom.sha1
   │   │           ├── maven-metadata.xml
   │   │           ├── maven-metadata.xml.md5
   │   │           └── maven-metadata.xml.sha1
   ```

Comment: Adding @aar at the end of dependency url and using v1.0 api of Bitbucket instead of v2.0 worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
add   authentication {

            basic(BasicAuthentication)
        }

        maven {
            credentials {
                username ''
                password ''
            }
            authentication {
                basic(BasicAuthentication)
            }
            url "https://bitbucket.org/USER/REPO/raw/BRANCH/"
        }
    }
```