# Private bitbucket maven repo

Tags: android, maven, gradle, bitbucket

I'm having trouble with a project using a private bitbucket maven repo, it was previously working but since upgrading to android studio RC gradle cannot find the repo whilst it is set to private. Unchecking the "This is a private repository" option on bitbucket resolves the issue but this isn't a viable solution.

Comment: How do you define this repo in gradle? Checked this one http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:maven_repo?

Comment: Similar to how it is in there but without the credentials block. The url is https://username:password@bitbucket..... and username and password are defined in gradle.properties

Comment: Could you show beginning of the string (with fake user and password)? Do you use "${username}"?

Comment: in gradle.properties it was defined as username=username same for password and in the url it was "https://"+username+":"... but I also tried hard coding them in there too and nothing.

Comment: did someone found any solution to this. putting username and password in url doesn't work.

Comment: you should see my answer in another question.
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/49912378/5302807](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49912378/5302807)

Comment: I am using https://repsy.io for private maven repo needs. It's simple and easy.

Answer (score 0):

I used to struggle against this problem a year ago. The solution was to use [synergian plugin](https://github.com/synergian/wagon-git). It uses your native `git` client and its configuration so there is no need to provide your credentials in plain text but use a RSA key. Give it a try and you won't regret.

Comment: Can anyone could describe in detail this solution ? I cannot upload release on my private bitbucket repository (probably problem of authentification)

Comment: [Here](http://synergian.github.io/wagon-git/bitbucket.html) is the documentation of the plugin

Comment: I already read it but with gradle in Android Studio I cannot succed to upload my aar release (event if I set my Bitbucket repository to "public" instead of "private". In the gradle process log the last line is : Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git pull origin releases" but nothing happen

Comment: Unfortunately currently I don't have access to the code where I used the plugin so I can't post you the exact lines... can you post your plugin configuration so I can take a look?

Comment: allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {url "https://raw.github.com/synergian/wagon-git/releases"}
    }
}
configurations {deployerJar}
dependencies {
    deployerJar 'ar.com.synergian:wagon-git:0.2.5'}
uploadArchives {
    repositories.mavenDeployer {
        configuration = rootProject.configurations.deployerJar
        pom.groupId = com.test
        pom.artifactId = testdeploy
        pom.version = 1.0.0
        repository(url: "git:releases://git@bitbucket.org:mylogin/aarlibraries.git") {
           //authentication(userName: 'mylogin', password: 'myPassowrd') }}}

Comment: Does this throw an error or isn't called at all? According to the documentation `userName` should be `username`. Have you tried authenticating using RSA key instead of credentials?

Comment: actually I think that the problem come from the rsa key authentification? I affraid the the git commande launched by the plugin (maven or wagon??) don't use the key defined under my /.ssh user directory, but there is no error, a temporary local git directory is created and a command "pull" is launched (according to log) but the process never stop (probably waiting for a confirmation ????)

Comment: It might be because I have a Pass Phrase confirmation in my RSA key, I don't know how to manage this

Comment: Why don't you generate a new RSA key without a pass phrase? Also you can try to remove the RSA keys and use only the plugin configuration (username and password).

Comment: I think I have also another problem: wagon-git lauch the git command with classic windows cmd (instead of Bash git) which lead to a "permission denied" even if I set a local windowd variable "HOME" = %userprofile% (to indicate where is my .ssh directory

Comment: I haven't tried this on windows machine (only on linux). Why don't you try to login using credentials and https protocol? I'm not sure if it will work but I think it worths to try.

Comment: just a newbie question :in the gradle config How do you specifiy the branch name "releases" in an https url connection (like with a git url) ?

Comment: According to the [source code](https://github.com/synergian/wagon-git/blob/master/src/main/java/ar/com/synergian/wagongit/GitWagon.java#L100) of the plugin it seems you should do it the same way: `git:releases:https://bitbucket.org/youraccount/yourrepo.git`

Comment: now the build fail with msg : Could not publish configuration 'archives'
   > For input string: "https:"

Comment: Probably it is not supported... I would advise you to download the source of the plugin and check how it works. The logic is pretty straight forward.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110551/discussion-between-toofoo-and-kiril-aleksandrov).