# Gradle DSL method not found: 'credentials()'

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, bitbucket-api

I am trying to add a dependency from my private BitBucket account using the BitBucket API following the accepted answer to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28986224/is-it-possible-to-compile-bitbucket-dependency-via-ssh-gradle).

My project root level build.gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://bitbucket.org/api/2.0/repositories/{user}/{repo}/commit/{tag_num}'
        }
        credentials {
            username 'my_username'
            password 'my_password'
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error:(21, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'credentials()'
Possible causes:
    - The project 'USPLibraryClerk' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
    - The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
```

If I move the `credentials {}` to inside the `maven {}` block, nothing seems to update in terms of getting my repo.

```
maven {
    url 'https://bitbucket.org/api/2.0/repositories/{user}/{repo}/commit/{tag_num}'
    credentials {
        username 'my_username'
        password 'my_password'
    }
}
```

How do I fix this error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use somenthing like this:

```
repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            credentials {
                username 'xxxx'
                password 'xxxx'
            }
            url 'http://xxxxxxxx/repositories/releases/'
        }
  }
```

Here the [official doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sub:maven_repo).

Comment: I have already tried that, see later part of my question. The message does go away, but nothing appears to be fetched.

Comment: @kRiZ It is the official syntax. You should check the issue in other part of your script. What do it mean nothing appear to be fetched?